# manually create associations in LINQ to SQL designer

Tags: sql, linq, orm

I have only access to VIEWS in a SQL database that I am working on.  In the LINQ to SQL designer surface, I drop two views from the database.  These two views are created by the database owner from the same underlying table. Both views contain the primary key from the  table. However, the association between these two views are not automatically created.  How do I manually create the association that use the common pk in the views?  I remember that I once could drag the pk from one class and drop it on the other class's pk to create the association, but not any more.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is in the DBML designer, right click in the empty space. A menu will pop up. Select Add, and from there select Association. The dialog for configuring the association will then appear for you.